# does node-imap support proxy?if it does ,how?

Tags: node.js, proxy, imap

i am using node-imap to recieving email and mark unseen email as seen. i have scanned the [node-imap API](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap#api) , it seems that it does not support proxy, am i right? if it suppors proxy , how to do it. the normal imap demo is like this:

```
var Imap = require('imap'),
    inspect = require('util').inspect;

var imap = new Imap({
  user: 'mygmailname@gmail.com',
  password: 'mygmailpassword',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true
});

function openInbox(cb) {
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}
...
```

Comment: What kind of proxy exactly are you thinking about?

Comment: the kind which imap can use. i run this program on my vps, the gmail imap server get my vps's ip, i want to change the ip with proxy.

Answer (score 0):

`imap-simple-with-socks` npm package supports socks proxies

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on your answer?